# How to obtain Black-Scholes from displaced diffusion process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The displaced diffusion process is
$$
d(F_t+a)=\sigma(F_t+a)dW_t
$$

I have solved it and found it to be
$$
F_t={F_0\over\beta}
\exp\left(
-\frac 12\beta^2\sigma^2t + \beta\sigma W_t
\right)
-\frac{1-\beta}\beta F_0
$$

However, I can't seem to be able to get the Black-Scholes formula from here.

Here's what I have done:

$$
V_0=E[(F_t-K)^+]
$$

$$W_t=\sigma \sqrt t x$$

For the $V_0$ to be positive, I found that
$$x^* = -\log
\left(
{F_0\over \beta(K+(1-\beta)/\beta)F_0} 
+{\beta^2\sigma^2t\over 2\beta\sigma\sqrt t}\right
)$$

It does not seem right though as I can't get back the Black-Scholes formula.